# binding @NumberFormat , set comma as decimal separator?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

My problem is that I read from the db, numbers (BigDecimal) and I view them with DOT as decimal separator, but I would like to see them with COMMA.  I used the following code:
    @ NumberFormat (style = Style.NUMBER, pattern = "##,###,###.##")
    private BigDecimal number;

My application with the following architecture:
oracle db - hibernate - spring mvc

I need an automatic conversion without manually convert to string with DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {  
    DecimalFormat df =new DecimalFormat();  
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');  
    df.setGroupingUsed(false);  
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);  
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(32);  
    df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(32);  
    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class,df, true));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A BigDecimal is a BigDecimal. It doesn't have any intrinsic format.

Moreover, it's definitely **not** the job of an ORM like Hibernate to transform the data the way you want it displayed. Treat your entities as data, and use the appropriate NumberFormat in the presentation layer, when you need to display the data. Number formatting has nothing to do in the persistence layer.

EDIT: I misunderstood the question:

NumberFormat is locale-dependent. This means that `,` means "the group separator associated with the locale", and `'.'` means "the decimal separator associated with the locale".

If you want a dot as group separator and a comma as decimal separator, either use a locale that has these as separators by default, or use a DecimalFormat and [set the DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setDecimalFormatSymbols%28java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols%29) to the appropriate values.

Comment: I already know what you said but i'm asking what pattern i should use in my case. If pattern is ##,###,###.## i get 99,999,999.99 but i want 99.999.999,99

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood the question. Please see the edits in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Tostis' solution but using a globally applied @InitBinder:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalBindingInitializer {

  @InitBinder
  public void initBigDecimalBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, df, true));
  }
}
```